# Why does Laravel return a Db::table query as string(5) "Sally"

Tags: php, database, laravel

Why does laravel return a query with excess information.

Why does this query:

```
DB::table('emails')->where('sent', '0')->get();
```

Produce this stdClass entry:

```
["email"]=> string(21) "webmaster@example.com"
```

Instead of this:

```
["email"]=> "webmaster@example.com"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because Laravel queries return [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections). If you want to get an array, you should use [toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-toarray) helper method.

```
$collection = DB::table('emails')->where('sent', '0')->get();
$array = $collection->toArray();
```

Comment: I used first() and then $collection->sent.

Answer (score 0):

`get()` returns a collection of objects every time. That collection may have 0 or more objects in it, depending on the results of the query. So, you have to use `toArray()` to convert those into array.

Use this:

```
$data = DB::table('emails')->where('sent', '0')->get()->toArray();
print_r($data);
```